# what are environment hooks in catkin

Tags: catkin-make, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to understand what the setup.sh file does and how it changes my shell environment such that catkin builds correctly.

Simply to describe my motivation for understanding, there are times when I get into a dirty build state (genjava and rosjava freaking out about something), and I have to blow away build, devel directories, and maven repos and build from scratch.  However if I naively call `catkin_make`, `rosjava` and `genjava` start breaking all over the place because I no longer have a `setup.bash` file to source other than the `ros/indigo/setup.bash`.  So I end up in this weird place where my first build command has to be `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/path/to/src:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH catkin_make`.  Then I can source the proper `setup.bash` file, call `catkin_make`, and everything builds fine again.

I'd like to understand more about the env hooks because my hope is I can just prefix `catkin_make` with all the env variables to get an arbitrary set of troubled packages (i.e. rosjava and genjava) happy and have a single command to solve my problems.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253790/what-are-environment-hooks-in-catkin/) by [blakejwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29253/blakejwc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2017-02-03

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2017-02-03**:
Have you seen https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mechanics.html#environment-setup-files? It does describe what an environment hook is, but it doesn't go into the technical mechanism which makes them work.

**Comment by [blakejwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29253/blakejwc/) on 2017-02-06**:
I could only find mention of "env hooks" in the [Quickstart](https://goo.gl/vyzJff) and [Workspace Mechanisms](https://goo.gl/ie6B6C) sections.  They don't really describe what an "env hooks" are, just their existence and somehow helping define packages in a workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Environment hooks are shell scripts provided by a ROS package. Whenever you source the setup file in a workspace those environment hooks are also being sourced. They are being used to set / extend environment variables. E.g. the `ros` package has an environment hook which set the environment variable `ROSDISTRO_NAME` (see https://github.com/ros/ros/blob/bf3e45955e5c8aac2ab276d6b956b21bc13ddccc/core/roslib/env-hooks/10.ros.sh.em#L16) and `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` (see https://github.com/ros/ros/blob/bf3e45955e5c8aac2ab276d6b956b21bc13ddccc/core/roslib/env-hooks/10.ros.sh.em#L41).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2017-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blakejwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29253/blakejwc/) on 2017-02-07**:
What is the `@()`, `@{}@`, and `@[if/else]@` syntax?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2017-02-07**:
Files ending in `.em` are using the EmPy template engine, see http://www.alcyone.com/pyos/empy/

**Comment by [blakejwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29253/blakejwc/) on 2017-02-07**:
oh wow!  This is intense, and it explains a lot of what I am seeing.  Thank you!

**Comment by [bluenote](https://answers.ros.org/users/37779/bluenote/) on 2019-01-16**:
Is there an overview of what variables are defined by Catkin within EmPy templating? EDIT: I created a [follow up question](https://answers.ros.org/question/312942/catkin-empy-variables/) for that.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-01-16**:
Existing question: https://answers.ros.org/question/312942/catkin-empy-variables/